# Add a timer LM555C on Qucs

Tags: 555, circuit-design, qucs

Does anyone know how to add a timer on Qucs ? The component's navigation bar doesn't help at all, It confuses me, I can't find a timer. I wondering, perhaps It could be added through library. In this case, I need to add LM555C timer on my circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no model for that component. What you can do is to model it as explained [here](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/docs/tutorial/timer555.pdf).

Comment: I've downloaded the file related to 555 timer, Martin. But what do I need is the whole component. DO you have any software recommendation alternative to Qucs, Martin. Qucks seems not comfortable

Comment: It's not comfortable, but it is very powerful. You can separate the component model you need and then add it as a component file. _Multisim_ might represent a more comfortable option for your work, but it is not free software.

Comment: Oh thanks, I'll keep Qucs on my PC, but I think I should go with that Multisim. Thanks for your help Martin :D